# pct_change in pandas: couldn't have result

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Thing is I trying calculate growth rate about Adj Close price which in a CSV file.format for Adj Close in CSV is like:

```
Adj Close
836.52002
822.440002
817.880005
808.330017
809.039978
807.47998
```

this is my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas

Adj = pd.DataFrame([pd.read_csv('XXX.csv',usecols=["Adj Close"])])
returns = Adj.pct_change(1)
print returns
```

but output is NaN:

```
0        Adj Close
0           NaN
1           Na...
```

really appreciate if someone can help me！ Thanks！

Comment: One side comment: If you write "import pandas as pd" then there is not much of a point of also writing "import pandas".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is excessive. pd.read_csv() already creates a DataFrame:

```
Adj = pd.DataFrame([pd.read_csv('XXX.csv',usecols=["Adj Close"])])
```

Instead the script should look like this (note how the definition of Adj changes):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Adj = pd.read_csv('XXX.csv',usecols=["Adj Close"])
returns = Adj.pct_change(1)
print returns
```

and the rest of your code will give you get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks! but other error happened.    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'usecols'   is means can't choose specific column in CSV file？

Comment: What is the other error? The code worked in my environment

Comment: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'usecols'

Comment: Are you sure you aren't still explicitly using DataFrame() somewhere? That is the only explanation I can think of. I updated the answer to have the complete script.